# How is it possible that println works inside void method?

Tags: java, methods, void

```
public void debit (double amount){
    if (balance<amount){
        System.out.println("Amount withdrawn exceedes the current balance");
    }
    else {
        balance-=amount;
    }
}
```

When I call `toString` in main I get message "Amount withdrawn exceedes the current balance" and then `toString` content. How is it possible when method is void?

Comment: `void` means your function cannot `return` anything, and You are not **"returning"** but just **"outputting"** to console.

Comment: If you're interested in learning a programming language where the return type *must* indicate if the method runs side-effects, you might like [Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not return anything to any method which calls your method. Simply prints your message to the screen. Simple as that :)

Comment: Yea, makes sense. Thanks.